# Integration test in custom folder: Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'. No tests found for given includes

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing

Apologies if that post repeats many other, I've seen them all and tried all the suggested recipes, and yet the problem stays.

I have a SpringBoot project with Grails build, with the following structure:

```
mybike-rest
    src
        integration
            java
                com.bike
                    BorrowMyBikeApplicationTest
            resources
        main
            java
            ...
        test
            java
            ...
```

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group = 'java.bike'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '8'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs('./src/main/java')
        resources.srcDirs('./src/main/resources')
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs('./src/test/java')
        resources.srcDirs('./src/test/resources')
    }
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDirs('./src/integration/java')
        resources.srcDirs('./src/integration/resources')
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations{
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    testLogging { events "passed", "skipped", "failed" } // This is not needed, but I like to see which tests have run
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core'

    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integrationTestCompile configurations.compile
    integrationTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime configurations.runtime
    integrationTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
    integrationTestAnnotationProcessor configurations.testAnnotationProcessor

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

IntelliJ recognises my test correctly:

[image]

However, when I run the test in iJ, I get the following output:

```
> Task :cleanIntegrationTest
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileIntegrationTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processIntegrationTestResources
> Task :integrationTestClasses
> Task :integrationTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.bike.BorrowMyBikeApplicationTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 1s
8 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

When I run in command line as `gradlew clean iT -i`, I see the following output:

```
...
> Task :compileIntegrationTestJava
file or directory '/home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/src/integrationTest/java', not found
Excluding []
Excluding []
Caching disabled for task ':compileIntegrationTestJava' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileIntegrationTestJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'destinationDirectory' file /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/classes/java/integrationTest has been removed.
  Output property 'destinationDirectory' file /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/classes/java/integrationTest/com has been removed.
  Output property 'destinationDirectory' file /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/classes/java/integrationTest/com/bike has been removed.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileIntegrationTestJava'.
Full recompilation is required because no incremental change information is available. This is usually caused by clean builds or changing compiler arguments.
file or directory '/home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/src/integrationTest/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
Created classpath snapshot for incremental compilation in 0.006 secs. 1 duplicate classes found in classpath (see all with --debug).
:compileIntegrationTestJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 10,5,main]) completed. Took 0.643 secs.
:processIntegrationTestResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :processIntegrationTestResources
file or directory '/home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/src/integrationTest/resources', not found
Caching disabled for task ':processIntegrationTestResources' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':processIntegrationTestResources' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/resources/integrationTest has been removed.
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/resources/integrationTest/application.properties has been removed.
file or directory '/home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/src/integrationTest/resources', not found
:processIntegrationTestResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.019 secs.
:integrationTestClasses (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :integrationTestClasses
Skipping task ':integrationTestClasses' as it has no actions.
:integrationTestClasses (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:integrationTest (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :integrationTest
Excluding []
Caching disabled for task ':integrationTest' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':integrationTest' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
Finished generating test XML results (0.0 secs) into: /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/test-results/integrationTest
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.003 secs) into: /home/nmilyaev/Work/Intellij/mybike-rest/build/reports/tests/integrationTest
:integrationTest (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.149 secs.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
```

Honestly, I tried everything there under the moon, but something is amiss. Could anyone please help me spot what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of digging, and coming across this issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12618
and trying an example from this repository: https://github.com/pkainulainen/gradle-examples

I've come up with a theory that Gradle 6.x doesn't play nicely with junit-jupiter. Sadly, I've no proper fix, but the following 2 workarounds seem to work:

1. Replace Junit5 with Junit4
2. Replace

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

with

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Better ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer, @nestor-milyaev. I have a similar structure to your project and this is my scenario:

- Gradle 7.3
- Using the [discussion you linked to](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12618#issuecomment-603453114).
- Using JUnit 5 and excluding vintage.

> ```
> tasks.withType(Test) {
>     useJUnitPlatform {
>         excludeEngines 'junit-vintage'
>     }
>     testLogging {
>         events "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
>     }
> }
> ```

Now ITs are running as well as UTs.